# CS0051: Parameter type 'abstract class' is less accessible than method 'method'

Tags: c#, .net

I've been working with abstract classes for about a month and I'm not too familiar with debugging their errors. My error message reads "Inconsistent accessibility: parameter type 'ConcessionItem' is less accessible than method 'Person.AddConcessionItem(ConcessionItem)'". I believe the error is being thrown due to using abstract classes and interfaces but I don't think I've ever solved an error like this before.

Person.cs

```
public class Person
    {
        public decimal Cash;

        public string Name;

        public string PreferredConcessionSize;

        public Ticket Ticket;

        private List<ConcessionItem> concessionItems;

        public Person()
        {
            this.concessionItems = new List<ConcessionItem>();
        }

        public void AddConcessionItem(ConcessionItem item)
        {
            this.concessionItems.Add(item);
        }
    }
```

ConcessionItem.cs

```
abstract class ConcessionItem : IPurchasable
    {
        private string size;

        private decimal price;

        private int servingsRemaining;

        public ConcessionItem(string size)
        {
            this.Size = size;

            this.Initialize();
        }
    }
```

Comment: You have a public method in a public class (`AddConcessionItem`) that takes as a parameter an internal class (`ConcessionItem`).

Comment: The reason this is a problem is easy to understand. Consider what would happen if you were trying to call that method from a different assembly..how would you construct the `ConcessionItem` to pass into the method? You wouldn't be able to because it's internal.

Comment: Yes, I agree with the problem. However, I'm having trouble understanding the solution. (I'm using a code template with directions so it must be a small solution.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no relation to abstract classes.

In your code, class `Person` is `public`, while class `ConcessionItem` does not have an explicit access modifier. In that case, compiler implicitly uses `private`. In the end, you have a `public AddConcessionItem` which accepts a parameter of `private` class `ConcessionItem`

Comment: Ok, thanks! I had no idea that I could add access modifiers to abstract classes. Making the class read as (abstract public class ConcessionItem : IPurchasable) fixed my error.

Comment: Yes, access modifiers should be consistent in the code. The caller may be more private, than callee: private method may use public classes / methods, but not vice versa

Answer (score 1):

You have ConcessionItem.cs as default private. You would need to make it public to make it the same as Person.cs.

Comment: Ok, so I can declare an abstract class as public? (abstract public class ConcessionItem : IPurchasable)

Comment: That seems to have fixed my error. I had no idea that I could add an access modifier to an abstract class.